# Save changes to iptables

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

I've got iptables running, as I can use the following command...

sudo /sbin/iptables sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

but I cant do....

service iptables save
iptables: unrecognized service

How do I actually save these changes as the mapping stops when I restart the server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Ubuntu uses [UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) in the latest version, so most likely it doesn't have a SysV init script for *iptables*. If you don't feel comfortable with *UFW*, you may use `sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules` to store your current rules and then invoke `sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules` from *rc.local* (for example) to restore the rules on startup.

Or, you can add your own init script for *iptables* as specified [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicFirewall):

```
#!/bin/sh -e
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          iptables
# Required-Start:    mountvirtfs ifupdown $local_fs
# Default-Start:     S
# Default-Stop:      0 6
### END INIT INFO

# July 9, 2007
# James B. Crocker <ubuntu@james.crocker.name>
# Creative Commons Attribution - Share Alike 3.0 License (BY,SA)
# Script to load/unload/save iptables firewall settings.

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"

IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
IPTABLES_SAVE=/sbin/iptables-save
IPTABLES_RESTORE=/sbin/iptables-restore

IPTABLES_CONFIG=/etc/iptables.conf

[ -x $IPTABLES ] || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions


case "$1" in
start)
    log_action_begin_msg "Starting firewall"
        type usplash_write >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && usplash_write "TIMEOUT 120" || true
    if $IPTABLES_RESTORE < $IPTABLES_CONFIG ; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
    log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
        type usplash_write >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && usplash_write "TIMEOUT 15" || true
    ;;

stop)
    log_action_begin_msg "Saving current firewall configuration"
    if $IPTABLES_SAVE > $IPTABLES_CONFIG ; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    log_action_begin_msg "Flushing ALL firewall rules from chains!"
    if $IPTABLES -F ; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    log_action_begin_msg "Deleting ALL firewall chains [Warning: ACCEPTING ALL PORT SERVICES!]"
    if $IPTABLES -X ; then
        $IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
        $IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
        $IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    ;;

save)
    log_action_begin_msg "Saving current firewall configuration"
    if $IPTABLES_SAVE > $IPTABLES_CONFIG ; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    ;;

force-reload|restart)
    log_action_begin_msg "Reloading firewall configuration [Warning: POTENTIAL NETWORK INSECURITY DURING RELOAD]"
    $IPTABLES -F
    $IPTABLES -X
    if $IPTABLES_RESTORE < $IPTABLES_CONFIG ; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    ;;

*)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/iptables {start|stop|save|restart|force-reload}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: when you write about the saving of the iptables, does that mean that when i save them, the system will *automagically* get them on startup?

Comment: also, the script that you have shown isn't referenced in the link you have... so what is the point of the link?

Comment: @bharal As you can see, it is a link to a wiki page, which could be frequently changed. At the time of writing, the script was referenced there, but apparently that's not the case anymore. I suspect the rest of the answer may be outdated as well, so I'll try to verify that and update it soon.

Comment: ah, fair. Sorry, i'm new to a lot of the magic of "servers" and "unix", so i was unsure if i was missing some deeper truth. Also, i was frustrated, which is more (entirely, really) my fault than yours.

Answer (score 3):

Your iptables rule is active once you execute it. Issuing a restart merely restores your iptables config to however it was last saved. There is no need to do the restart.

```
iptables-save
iptables-restore
```

will save rules in a plain text file and it will be restored on system startup by the init.d script.  see iptables.conf e iptables man for details

Comment: your use of the word "usually" does not inspire any confidence. Is there a reason that a default system wouldn't do this?

Comment: I think it was something related spell checker lol

Comment: 'iptables-save' does not store anything, it just prints to STDOUT. use -f to tell it a file path.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it the easy way? In Debian/Ubuntu you can:

1 - create your iptables rules

2 - run `sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent`; it will ask you if you want to save the rules and restore them after boot.